# Data Lost while using post request in Python

Tags: python, curl

When I use curl command from a normal terminal, it is giving proper output.
But when I tried to run the same through py script, data received from the server is jumbled and not complete.

I tried after enabling cookies too, but still the same issue.

First one is working command, **WORKING**

```
curl http://serverXYZ.com/ABC -X  --max-time 10 POST -d "q=data&from=arg1&to=arg1"   //working fine, correct data
```

The second one, same logic when I tired in python.
**NOT WORKING**

```
/// Below one, data is jumbled and not complete
data = {
  'q': 'data',
  'from': 'arg1',
  'to': 'arg2'
}

result = requests.post('http://serverXYZ.com/ABC', data=data).json()
print(result)
```

Comment: Please describe what you get with NOT WORKING. Any Erorrs?

Comment: No error only received data is incorrect. For small data, there is no error, for big data, the data received is incorrect.

Comment: Can you share the data returned by the server in each case?

Comment: @kundan:   failed cases: development responsibility artificial number khaspur3khaspur3khaspur3khaspur problem description khaspur4khaspur4khaspur problem description

pass case : development responsibility artificial number khaspur3khaspur3khaspur problem description khaspur4khaspur1khaspur problem description

Answer (score 0):

Compare the headers of both requests and use the same headers as curl is using.

Comment: No access to server .